# How to download a file in terminal which link redirects and seems to work in GUI only?

Tags: wget, curl, download

I am trying to figure out a way to download this file:

```
zoiper5_5.2.6_x86_64.tar.xz
```

from this link:

```
https://www.zoiper.com/en/voip-softphone/download/zoiper5/for/linux
```

from this web page respectivelly:

```
https://www.zoiper.com/en/voip-softphone/download/current
```

where man needs to click on Linux Download -> Free -> `tar.xz` Package.

---

What I have tried:

```
curl -JLO https://www.zoiper.com/en/voip-softphone/download/zoiper5/for/linux

wget --user-agent=Mozilla --content-disposition -E -c https://www.zoiper.com/en/voip-softphone/download/zoiper5/for/linux
```

---

PS: If you download the file, note it's actually `bz2` file. A little crazy, I know :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To download that file, you need a cookie named `PHPSESSID`.

First, save the cookie:

```
curl \
  -c cookie.txt \
  -o /dev/null \
  https://www.zoiper.com/en/voip-softphone/download/current
```

Then, use that cookie and download the file:

```
curl \
  -b cookie.txt \
  -o zoiper5_5.2.6_x86_64.tar.xz \
  https://www.zoiper.com/en/voip-softphone/download/zoiper5/for/linux
```

You can also do it with [process substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Process-Substitution) to avoid writing a cookie file:

```
curl -b <( curl -c - -o /dev/null https://www.zoiper.com/en/voip-softphone/download/current ) -o zoiper5_5.2.6_x86_64.tar.xz https://www.zoiper.com/en/voip-softphone/download/zoiper5/for/linux
```